# Why do web accessible URLs in my extension break after the (unpacked) extension is reloaded?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am developing a Chrome extension which inserts images into the DOM whose src attributes point at chrome-extension:// URLs inside the extension itelf. These URLs are listed in manifest.json as web accessible resources for the pages on which they are inserted. I have the extension loaded into my browser as an unpacked extension during development.

When I first launch the browser, the images load fine in the web pages into which they are inserted. However, when I go to chrome://extensions and reload the extension and then reload the page into which the images were previously inserted, I see the broken image icon instead of the inserted image, and I see this error in my console:

> Denying load of chrome-extension://afjdfegpgbfjgdelebopglhhfkjjblch/icons/16.png. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

Note that the URL listed in the error is the correct URL for the image, and if I load that URL in its own tab it works fine.

If I quit and restart the browser, the images start loading in the page again.

This same issue occurs if I'm attempting to fetch these exact same image URLs using `fetch()` in my content script -- the fetch works when I first launch the browser, but then it fails with the error above if I reload the extension and then reload the page.

I thought maybe specifying `use_dynamic_url` for the images in manifest.json would help, but it has no effect on the problem.

I don't want to have to quit and restart my browser every time I need to reload the extension during development, and I don't want my extension to break for users until they quit and restart their browsers every time I release a new version and Chrome updates the extension in the background (though, to be clear, I do not know for certain that this problem occurs in that context; I only know for certain that it occurs when the extension is installed unpacked).

Any idea what's going on here and how I can fix it?

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome. Either try reverting to ManifestV2 or convert the image data to a blob URL via fetch + URL.createObjectURL.

Comment: As I noted in my question, the same problem occurs in the content script if I use fetch, so converting to a blob URL doesn't work. I've resorted to converting the image into a base64 URL at compile time and embedding that URL in the content script.

Comment: I see. My idea was for the case you only need to add the icons once per browsing session, not per each reload of the extension.